# Expo project fails to compile when using react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo, react-navigation

I am building an expo project and wanted to add navigation. Expo recommends react-navigation, so I attempted to install it.

1. I made a basic app
2. Wanted to add navigation so I followed the official guide on Expo.io
3. `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`
4. `npm install @react-navigation/stack`
5. `import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';`

Whenever I attempt to open the project on my iPhone or Web Browser, I get the following error...

[image]

I have tried every fix given on the troubleshooting page https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/ ( accept for deleting the node modules and running `npm install` again ), and I have still not been able to fix the issue.

I have found people with this issue but have never found a fix that has worked for me.

I was recommended Expo by a friend of mine and so far my experience has been rather "ehh". I have had a few people tell me they also have TONS of issues with Expo and tell me to just use `React Native`, but the issue there is that I am a windows dev and I cant test IOS on React Native, and I only have an iPhone and I am not going to build an app I can't use myself. TBH, I don't even find React useful or fun ( as a svelte dev ) but I am willing to try React ( after ditching it 3 times because of trivial stuff like this ).

Does anyone know a fix to this issue? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `@react-navigation/native`:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

It's the first command in the installation docs for React Navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installation (and also mentioned in the troubleshooting doc: `npm install name-of-the-module`)

> I was recommended Expo by a friend of mine and so far my experience has been rather "ehh". I have had a few people tell me they also have TONS of issues with Expo and tell me to just use React Native,

This has nothing to do with Expo. Expo wraps React Native's bundler, so if you have an issue with bundling or dependencies in Expo, you'll have it in React Native, except worse coz you also have to deal with native code.